# Two random variables where one is dependent on the other

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> Find discrete random variables $Y,X$ such that $$E(X\vert Y)=E(X)\quad \text{and}\quad E(Y\vert X)\neq E(Y)$$

I'm pretty sure I can do this with indicator functions. So my attempt:

$X\sim Ber(1/4)\quad$ and $\quad Y=1_{X=1}$

$E(X|Y)=E(X)=1/4$

$$E(Y)=P(X=1)\neq E(Y|X=k)=\frac{E(1_{X=k}1_{X=1})}{P(X=x)}$$

Here I'm stucked. How do I compute $E(Y\vert X)$? 
What confuses me is that $1_{X=k}1_{X=1}=1_{X=k\cap X=1}=1_{k=1}$. So what is $P(k=1)$?

---

My  second question is concerning independance. I often struggle to see whether two events are independent or not.

For instance if I have $Z=X+Y$ and $X,Y$ are independent. It's clear that $Z$ is not independent of $X$. But is $X$ independent of $Z$? If I write $X=Z-Y$ Then it looks like it is dependent.

Comment: is that supposed to be $E(Y|X) \neq E(Y)$ in the problem statement?

Comment: @GabrielBurns Yes my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm going to explain conditional expectation using the random variables you've given.

> Definition: If $X$ is a discrete random variable with values $\{x_1, x_2, ...x_n\}$, then
>
> $$E[Y|X] := \sum_{i=1}^{n} E[Y|X=x_i]1_{X=x_i}$$

So, $E[Y|X]$ is a random variable, but $E[Y|X=x_i]$ is a number, which I guess you already know is defined as $$E[Y|X=x_i] := \frac{E[Y1_{X=x_i}]}{P(X=x_i)}$$

---

In your case we have

$$E[Y|X] = E[Y|X=1]1_{X=1} + E[Y|X=0]1_{X=0}$$

while

$$E[Y] = P(X=1) = \frac14$$

If $X=1$, then

$$E[Y|X] = E[Y|X=1]1_{X=1}$$

$$= \frac{E[Y 1_{X=1}]}{P(X=1)}1_{X=1}$$

$$= \frac{E[Y (1)]}{(1/4)}(1)$$

$$= 1$$

$$\ne E[Y]$$

If $X=0$, then

$$E[Y|X] = E[Y|X=0]1_{X=0}$$

$$= \frac{E[Y 1_{X=0}]}{3/4}1_{X=0}$$

$$= \frac{E[Y (1)]}{(3/4)}(1)$$

$$= \frac{E[(0) (1)]}{(3/4)}(1)$$

$$= 0$$

$$\ne E[Y]$$

Thus, we have $$E[Y] \ne E[Y|X]$$

In fact, we have $$E[Y|X] = Y$$

In advanced probability theory, this is because $Y$ is $X$-measurable.

In elementary probability theory (read: intuitively), this is because if we know $X$, then we know $Y$ so there is no 'expectation'.

---

As for $E[X|Y]$, we have

$$E[X|Y] = E[X|Y=1]1_{Y=1} + E[X|Y=0]1_{Y=0}$$

If $Y=1$, then

$$E[X|Y] = E[X|Y=1]1_{Y=1}$$

$$= \frac{E[X 1_{Y=1}]}{P(Y=1)}1_{Y=1}$$

$$= \frac{E[X 1_{X=1}]}{P(X=1)}(1)$$

$$= \frac{E[(1) 1_{X=1}]}{1/4}(1)$$

$$= \frac{P(X=1)}{1/4}(1)$$

$$= 1$$

If $Y=0$, then

$$E[X|Y] = E[X|Y=0]1_{Y=0}$$

$$= \frac{E[X 1_{Y=0}]}{P(Y=0)}1_{Y=0}$$

$$= \frac{E[X 1_{X=0}]}{(3/4)}(1)$$

$$= \frac{E[(0) 1_{X=0}]}{(3/4)}(1)$$

$$= 0$$

Thus $E[X|Y]$ is not constant. Actually, $E[X|Y] = Y$

I am not sure how to explain this intuitively.

Therefore, we do not have $E[X] = E[X|Y]$

---

Actually, the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are equal, if I'm not mistaken. At the very least they are almost surely equal, meaning $P(X = Y) = 1$.

Let me be a little more precise without using (too much?) advanced probability.

Suppose we have a (discrete) [probability space](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/crypto/Overheads/03_prob.pdf) $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$.

Let $X \sim \text{Ber}(\frac14)$. One such $X$ is $$X=1_A, \ \text{where} A \subseteq \Omega, P(A) = \frac14$$

Let $Y=1_{X=1}$.

I am claiming that if we collect all the sample points $\omega$ in $\Omega$ into the event $\{X(\omega) = Y(\omega)\} (\subseteq \Omega)$, then $\{X(\omega) = Y(\omega)\}$ is the entire sample space $\Omega$ itself, if I'm not mistaken. At the very least $P(\{X(\omega) = Y(\omega)\}) = 1$

Pf:

Consider any sample point $\omega$ in the sample space $\Omega$.

Case 1: $\omega \in A$

Then $X(\omega) = 1_A(\omega) = 1$

In other words,

$$\omega \in \{X(\omega) = 1\}$$

$$\to Y(\omega) = 1_{X=1}(\omega) = 1$$

Thus $X=Y (=1)$ if $\omega \in A$.

Case 2: $\omega \notin A$

Then $X(\omega) = 1_A(\omega) = 0$

In other words,

$$\omega \notin \{X(\omega) = 1\}$$

$$\to \omega \in \{X(\omega) \ne 1\}$$

$$\to \omega \in \{X(\omega) = 0\} \tag{1}$$

$$\to Y(\omega) = 1_{X=1}(\omega) = 0$$

Thus $X=Y (=0)$ if $\omega \notin A$.

QED...?

The possible flaw in the above reasoning is that an alternative definition of $X$ may make $(1)$ false. Consider a different $X$ s.t.

$$X=1_A + 10 \times 1_B$$

where $P(A)=\frac14$ and $P(B)=0$ so X technically could be $10$ for some $\omega$'s in $\Omega$, but there are too few of those sample points to the extent that $P(X=10)=P(\{X(\omega) = 10\})=P(\{\omega | X(\omega) = 10\})=0$.

I think all this depends on how we define our sample space. If we toss a 6-sided die, is a roll of 7 going to be part of the sample space $\Omega$ as follows:

$$\{\text{roll of 1}, ..., \text{roll of 6}, \text{roll of 7}\}$$

with $P(\text{roll of 7}) = 0$? Or do we say that

$$\Omega = \{\text{roll of 1}, ..., \text{roll of 6}\}$$

?

Here, $\text{roll of 7} \notin \Omega \to \text{roll of 7} \in \emptyset \to P(\text{roll of 7}) = 0$.

---

FYI, it can actually be shown that

$$E[X|Y] = Y \ \text{and} \ E[Y|X] = X \to P(X=Y) = 1$$

Proving it is unbelievably complicated if we do not assume $E[X^2], E[Y^2] < \infty$.

Otherwise, we can show $E[(X-Y)^2] = 0$ (assuming we know $E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]$, which in turn assumes we know what the Hell '$E[E[X|Y]]$' means) to get $X-Y=0 \ \text{a.s.}$

In your case, we can show that $E[X|Y] = Y$. We have so far only that $E[Y|X] = Y$. I'm not sure how we can show $E[Y|X] = X$ without using $X=Y$.

---

For completeness, I'm going to give an answer based on another answer.

Consider discrete probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb P)$, and let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ be events ($A_i \subseteq \Omega$) s.t. $P(A_i) = \frac13$.

Define $X=1_{A_1}-1_{A_2}+0 \times 1_{A_3}$ and $Y=1_{X=1} + 1_{X=-1}+0 \times 1_{X=0}$

Obviously, $E[X]=0$ and $E[Y]=\frac23$

It can be shown that

$$E[X|Y] = 0$$

Thus

$$E[X|Y] = E[X]$$

This means that knowledge of $Y$ doesn't change what we expect $X$ will be, on average:

If $Y=0$, then definitely $X=0$. So obviously on average, $X=0$. Precisely: $X=0 \to E[X] = 0$.

If $Y=1$, then $X$ is either $1$ or $-1$ but with equal probability so on average, $X=0$. Precisely: $P(X=1|Y=1) = P(X=-1|Y=1) \to E[X|Y=1] = 0$

Also,

$$E[Y|X] = 1_{X=1} + 1_{X=-1}$$

This means

1. $E[Y|X]$ is not constant and hence $\ne E[Y]$. Specifically, $E[Y|X]$ varies w/rt to X meaning knowledge of $X$ changes we expect $Y$ will be, on average:

   - If $X=1$, then definitely $Y=1$. So obviously $Y=1$, on average. Precisely: $Y=1 \to E[Y] = 1$
   - If $X=-1$, then definitely $Y=1$. So obviously $Y=1$, on average. Precisely: $Y=1 \to E[Y] = 1$
   - If $X=0$, then definitely $Y=0$. So obviously $Y=0$, on average. Precisely: $Y=0 \to E[Y] = 0$
2. $$E[Y|X] = Y$$

As with earlier and as can be seen from 1, if we know $X$, then we know $Y$ so there is no 'expectation'.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly the answer I was looking for! Now everything is much more clearer to me! Just one question. You wrote: $$\frac{E[Y1_{X=0}]}{3/4}1_{X=0}$$
And then on the next line you have
$$\frac{E[Y(1)]}{3/4}(1)$$
shouldn't this be
$$\frac{E[Y(0)]}{3/4}(0)$$?
Or am I missing something? What does your notation $(1)$ exactly stand for?

Comment: @Matriz you're welcome! $Y(0)=Y \times 0$

Comment: @Matriz Wasn't satisfied with my 'answer' because 1 I didn't actually answer the question and 2 I kept thinking about whether or not $X=Y$ so edited

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $E(X|Y) = E(X)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. And then you just need $E(Y) \ne E(X)$.

As for your second question, "$X$ is independent of $Z$" means exactly the same thing as "$Z$ is independent of $X$".

EDIT: For the revised question, $X$ and $Y$ can't be independent.  However, you can still get $E(X|Y) = E(X)$ if you choose values carefully.  Try a 
case with three different possible outcomes, each equally likely:

1. $X = x_1$, $Y = 0$
2. $X = x_2$, $Y = 1$
3. $X = x_3$, $Y = 1$

For $E(X) = E(X|Y)$, you need $x_1 = (x_2 + x_3)/2$.

Comment: I think that may have been a typo.  His work suggests he's actually trying to ensure that $E(Y|X) \neq E(Y)$, meaning $X$ and $Y$ can't be independent.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it was a typo. Should be $E(Y|X)\neq E(Y)$

Comment: Thank you very much and I'm sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=\mathsf E(X)$ means that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ has a mean that is independent of $Y$, but *may* have a varying spread (ie support or variance).

Try $(X,Y)\sim\mathcal U\{(0,0),(-1,1),(1,1)\}$

---

> Then $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=0~\mathbf 1_{Y=0}+\frac{(1-1)}2~\mathbf 1_{Y=1} = 0=\mathsf E(X)$

---

> But $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=0~\mathbf 1_{X\in\{0\}}+1~\mathbf 1_{X\in\{-1,1\}}\neq \frac 23=\mathsf E(Y)$